# Managing Templates on Member Functions

Tags: c++, templates, function, member

```
class myclass {
   // Definitions of cotrs and dtor...
   // ...
   // Defining a method of mine that needs a template
   template < typename T >
   void dosome(T& par);
}
```

What to do in implementation in cpp file?
I thought ti was good this:

```
template <typename T>
void myclass::dosome< T >(T& par) {
   // My code
}
```

But compiler gets really mad...
What's the syntax in this context? Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is the one used for functions:

```
template<typename T> void myclass::dosome(T &par) {
  // ...
}
```

However, normally you should include template definitinos in the header.

Comment: Yes, it is correct, I tried a moment later... Thank you. Ah, one question, what do you mean by: "put it in the header"?

Comment: @Andry - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111932/where-to-put-a-member-function-template

Answer (score 4):

You want the entire template definition in the header.

Comment: No, I do not want the template to be applied to the entire class, just to the method.

Comment: Ok I could manage it, it was almost correct, what told me J. Calleja is a better way to do it but the compiler finally accepted both, there was a bug somewhere else.. :)

Comment: "what told me J. Calleja is a better way to do"   No, Calleja told you to put it in the header, too. If you put the definition of a template method in a CPP file, it will *only be available* in that translation unit. In other words, you won't be able to use that template in other CPP files.