# Where/how is xstrtoul() defined?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, glibc, gnu-coreutils

I was looking through the code for `ls.c` and noticed a call to `xstrtoul()`. I wanted to find out where exactly was this useful function defined. This led me to `xstrtol.h`, which has the following snippet:

```
# define _DECLARE_XSTRTOL(name, type) \
  strtol_error name (const char *, char **, int, type *, const char *);
_DECLARE_XSTRTOL (xstrtol, long int)
_DECLARE_XSTRTOL (xstrtoul, unsigned long int)
_DECLARE_XSTRTOL (xstrtoimax, intmax_t)
_DECLARE_XSTRTOL (xstrtoumax, uintmax_t)
```

If I understand this correctly, the resulting function prototype after the preprocessor pass would be:

```
strtol_error xstrtoul (const char *, char **, int, unsigned long int *, \
                                                                   const char *);
```

Yet, the only related function defined in `xstrtol.c` is `__xstrtol()`, which has the following signature:

```
strtol_error
__xstrtol (const char *s, char **ptr, int strtol_base,
           __strtol_t *val, const char *valid_suffixes)
```

My guess is that somehow, the compiler is mapping multiple instances of this function each time with another name substituted for `__xstrtol` and another type for `__strtol_t`. But I don't understand where/how this is done. (There is only a `#define` for each of those two at the top of `xstrtol.c`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the `xstrtol.c` file is where the function is really defined, but this source file is **included** into other source files, acting like a C++ function template, to generate functions with slightly different names and behavior.

Look at [xstrtoul.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/xstrtoul.c). It actually includes [xstrtol.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/xstrtol.c) but defines several preprocessor symbols to modify the template function generation:

```
#define __strtol strtoul
#define __strtol_t unsigned long int
#define __xstrtol xstrtoul
#define STRTOL_T_MINIMUM 0
#define STRTOL_T_MAXIMUM ULONG_MAX
#include "xstrtol.c"
```

It's unusual (but not unheard-of) to include a `.c` file into another `.c` file.

In C++, there are file naming conventions used for the similar situation where template definitions are [defined in a `.tcc` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4111960/994153) which is `#included` at the end of a `.hpp` header file.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was exploring the debuginfo of coreutils, which only has the single xstrtol.c file, not the whole family like in the git tree.